# Trouble creating multiple time series object in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a pretty simple CSV / data frame with 5 time series that looks like this:

```
date ts1 ts2 ts3 ts4 ts5
2000  1   4   6   10   3
2001  4   11  4   8    4
2002  7   23  5   9    15
2003  8   8   3   10   8
2004  3   9   1   9    7
```

I am trying to turn this into a "MTS" object, such that I can use the R package, VARS. I am very new to R, have been googling and cannot seem to find an easy way. There must be one line of code or something in an import statement that does this for me?

I have reviewed the VARS vignette and there is nothing in there. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vignettes/vars.pdf

Thank you for the help.

Comment: If the above is a `data.frame` named "Data", 
`mtsData <- ts(Data[,-1],frequency=1, start=2000,class="mts")`.

Comment: what is the point of the Data[,-1] ?

Comment: It just means "use all of the columns in the `Data` except for the first". I'm assuming you don't plan to use `date` as a variable, and since it will be included as the `tsp` attribute of the `mtsData` object via the specification `frequency=1,start=2000`, there's no reason to include it with columns 2 through 6.